# How to make a "Staggered Grid" in Semantic UI

Tags: css, android-layout, user-interface, web-applications, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI for the CSS styling and couldn't find any documentation regarding a staggered grid view. Has anyone implemented it yet or any ideas how to?
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry if it is unclear. I want to implement a staggered grid view(this is popular in Android) but semantic UI documentation lacks any info on this. So I wanted to know if there is a way of implementing it in some way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a layout that looks like Pinterest where grid items are in fixed width columns but the aspect ratio of the content inside those columns stagger the gaps between items at uneven points. It is kind of like a masonry layout rotated 90 degrees.

Unfortunately Semantic UI does not have support for masonry or staggered grid layouts with their grid system. Depending on your needs and your environment you may want to check out a tool like [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Comment: Fantastic! Glad that worked for you. Please consider marking this answer as correct if it was helpful to you.